# WooCommerce/WordPress: how hide entire table form after submit (Admin Dashboard)?

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, forms, table

#### Desired outcome

I want `display: none` to be applied to the entire `table` after form `submit` button is clicked,
because once I got the order number ( `$order->get_id()` ), in a second step I want to display the order details and a second form table to edit the weights of each item (and the initial form table with the list of orders would take too much space).
(if required or helpful I can post screenshots of the two form tables).

#### Observations

I saw that with `onsubmit="this.style.display='none'"` (which I did not combine with the `javascript` code variations) the table cell holding the `submit button` clicked briefly became only a few pixels in height (but did not disappear entirely), but reappeared after a few seconds.

#### Steps including code

I made a plugin with a function hooked to `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page` 's.

```
add_menu_page( 
        'Packing-App', // $page_title
        'Pack-App', // $menu_title
        'manage_options', // $capability
        'pg-packapp1', // $menu_slug
        'fn_packapp1', // $function
        'dashicons-tickets', // $icon_url
    54 // $position
);

add_submenu_page( 
        'pg-packapp1', // $parent_slug
        'All Open Orders', // $page_title
        'Open Orders', // $menu_title
        'manage_options', // $capability
        'pg-packapp1', // $menu_slug
        'fn_packapp1' // callable $function = ''
        // int $position = null
);
    
add_submenu_page( 
        'pg-packapp1', // $parent_slug
        'One Open Order', // $page_title
        'One Order', // $menu_title
        'manage_options', // $capability
        'pg-packapp2', // $menu_slug
        'fn_packapp2' // callable $function = ''
        // int $position = null
);
```

Next, I made a query on `on-hold` orders.

```
$on_hold_orders = wc_get_orders( 
    array (
        'limit' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'status'    => 'on-hold'
    )
);
```

Then, I created a `form` inside a `table` (wrapped in a `<div>` element) using a `foreach` loop.
(For simplicity, I omitted table header and other table cells here...)

```
$edit_form1 = ' edit';
foreach( $on_hold_orders as $order) {
    ?>
    <div class="table1" id="table1">
    <tr>
    <td>    
    <form 
        onsubmit="this.style.display='none'"
        id="form_1"
        name="form_order_id"
        action="#"
        method="post"
        >
                
        <input 
            type="hidden" 
            name="frub_id"
            value="<?= $order->get_id() ?>"
        />
        
        <input 
            onclick="myClick()"
            type="submit" 
            name="<?= $order->get_id() ?>"
            value="<?= $order->get_id() . $edit_form1 ?>"
        />
        </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
```

Once the form `submit` button is pressed, I want to hide the entire table.
I tried some `javascript` code, but to no avail:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* 3rd attempt */
        function myClick(){
            var form = document.getElementById("form_order_id");
            form.style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("form_1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("9275").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("table_id").style.display = "none";
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    
        /* 2nd attempt */
        document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "none";
        }
        
        /* 1st attempt */
        document.forms['form_order_id'].addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            this.style['display'] = 'none';
            event.preventDefault();
        });
</script>
```

P.S. I am still a rookie coder, I am thankful for any aid.

Answer (score 0):

So I would take of on your html form the onsubmit()=..., once isnt needed and your javascript function should only have something like this.

```
document.getElementById("form_1").style.display = "none";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("form_1").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

this should do the job, if for some reason it does not, change the onclick from the input to the form tag.

Your code should look like so:

```html
<form onclick="myClick()" id="form_1" name="form_order_id" action="#" method="post" >               
   <input type="hidden" name="frub_id" value="<?= $order->get_id() ?>" />
   <input type="submit" name="<?= $order->get_id() ?>" value="<?= $order->get_id() . $edit_form1 ?>" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myClick(){
      document.getElementById("form_1").style.display = "none";
   }
</script>
```